# Passing multidimensional arrays to a function

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

The point of the program is to send data from 1 array to another array I'm not sure what's wrong with how I'm passing it. It should enter the data in 1 array then call upon the copy function and puts itself there and then the array is traversed.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdbool.h>


double copy_arr(double source[n][u],double target[n][u],int n,int u);

int main(void)
{
    double source[3][5]={{1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5},
                 {1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5},
                     {1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5}};
    double target1[3][5];


    copy_arr(source,target1,3,5);

    int j;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
        printf("%f 1",target1[i][j]);

        }
    }



    return 0;
}

double copy_arr(double source[][],double target[][],int n,int u)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       for(j=0;j<u;j++)
       {
          target[i][j] = source[i][j];
       }
    }

    return target[n][u];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function prototype is wrong because compiler has not seen `n` and `u` yet. Your program does not even compile. 
Change

```
 double copy_arr(double source[n][u],double target[n][u],int n,int u);
```

to

```
 double copy_arr(int n,int u,double source[n][u],double target[n][u]);
```

Comment: thanks :D i didnt think it mattered because it worked that way with a 1 dimentional array

Comment: But this is the case of 2 dimensional array. :D

Comment: Actuall only `u` needs to be seen before the array declarations, as the leading array dimension isn't part of the variable array parameter type.  Which is also why it 'works' with 1D arrays...

Comment: @ChrisDodd; Yes you are right. That's fine for `source[][u]`. But for `source[n][u]`, `n` is also not seen by the compiler at that time that's why you need to pass it.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do hardcoded array size

```
#define SIZE_ARR 5

void copy_arr(double source[][SIZE_ARR], double target[][SIZE_ARR], int n, int u);

int main(void)
{
    double source[3][SIZE_ARR]={{1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5},
                         {1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5},
                         {1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5}};
    double target1[3][SIZE_ARR];


    copy_arr(source,target1, 3, 5);

    int j;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("%f 1",target1[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void copy_arr(double source[][SIZE_ARR], double target[][SIZE_ARR], int n, int u)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
       for(j=0;j<u;j++)
       {
          target[i][j] = source[i][j];
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I never seen such type of function prototype in C!! I think for multidimensional arrays you must specify column rather than row, Isn't it?

Comment: @haccks Thanks, I am not awake today :-)